# Typeahead function in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image]

Due to a bad flickering at the box typeahead.js with the results, I have to use jquery ui autocomplete.

I was wondering if there was a chance to create a function "typeahead", see written in gray on the photo, on ui autocomplete.

Is there a way to do this?